# set client context in sharepoint javascript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I have the following code which iterates for subsites:

```
 while (enumSubSites.moveNext())
        {
            var Site = enumSubSites.get_current();
```

I want to get the associates list items from Site. Do I need to somehow set client context to retrieve list items?

Answer (score 0):

Try like following

Get the list

```
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('List Name');
```

Create Query

```
var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();  
caml.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='Title' /><Value Type='Text'>T</Value></BeginsWith></Where></Query></View>");
```

Specify the query and load the list oject

```
returnedItems = list.getItems(caml);  
context.load(returnedItems);
```

Run asynchronously

```
context.executeQueryAsync(onSucceededCallback, onFailedCallback);
```